# Celery application with no serialization at all

Tags: serialization, celery, kombu

My Django app doesn't need any serialization at all. The data transfered between app and the worker consists purely of ascii strings. Of course default serialization works and json keep them untouched, but I would like to turn it off completely.

There is a note in [Kombu documentation](http://kombu.readthedocs.io/en/master/userguide/serialization.html#sending-raw-data-without-serialization) on how to send data without serialization but for me it is not clear how to incorporate it into Celery.

I just can't find relevant information in the docs. If someone could point me to it or provide an example that would be great.

Is it possible to do it without registering a serializer? Can I just pass something as a `serializer` task option?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have around 50 MB of data that is already in JSON and celery takes 15 seconds to serialize it, I would really like to turn that off to speed things up.